# How to access Moodle code on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, moodle

I have already used moodle code in wamp, now I have used the same code on ubuntu and added it in `/var/www` directory. I have installed lamp too, but it is giving me the following error:

```
Error: Database connection failed
It is possible that the database is overloaded or otherwise not running properly.
```

The site administrator should also check that the database details have been correctly specified in `config.php`.

But when I am using other php curd operation it works but for Moodle it gives errors.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the config.php isn't set up correctly. Check the database settings in config.php

```
$CFG->dbtype    = 'mysqli'; // assuming it's mysql
$CFG->dblibrary = 'native';
$CFG->dbhost    = 'localhost';
$CFG->dbname    = 'moodledatabasename';
$CFG->dbuser    = 'moodledatabaseusername';
$CFG->dbpass    = 'moodledatabasepassword';
```

Comment: fast is my middle name... my mom has a funny sense of humour ;)